# How to input string to function?

Tags: python, python-module

Here are the instructions I received for my assignment:

4) Add the following function into  Mylib

```
scalc(p1)
p1 will be a string like this "N1, N2, operator"
examples
scalc("20,30,*")
the result will be 600

scalc("50,20,+")
the result will be 70

scalc("50,20,-")
the result will be 30

scalc("60,20,/")
the result will be 30
```

use string functions to parse the first number, the second number, and the operator from the input string.
use the prior functions (add, subtract, divide and multiply ) to do the calculations.

---

And here is my attempt that is not working.  I have the add() sub() mult() div() functions, I'm just not showing them here.

I know it's something very simple that likely has to do with where I call the function scalc(p1).  What is the proper way to do that?

```
def scalc(p1):
    astring = p1.split(",")
    num1 = float(astring[0])
    num2 = float(astring[1])
    if astring[3] == "+":
        add()
    elif astring[3] == "-":
        sub()
    elif astring[3] == "*":
        mult()
    elif astring[3] == "/":
        div()
    return num1, num2

p1 = input("Enter two numbers and an operator, each separated by a comma: ")
scalc(p1)
```

**EDIT: Here is the Answer.  I did not have arguments being passed to my functions.  By adding num1 and num2 to every instance of my arithmetic functions, they were able to receive the new variable values.**

```
#Define the main program function
def main():
    #Define input function
    def float_input(msg):
        while True:
            try:
                return float(input(msg))
            except ValueError:
                print("You must enter a number!")
            else:
                break
    #Declare variables        
    rangeLower = float_input("Enter your Lower range: ")
    rangeHigher = float_input("Enter your Higher range: ")
    num1 = float_input("Enter your First number: ")
    num2 = float_input("Enter your Second number: ")

    #Define formula functions
    def add(num1, num2):
        sum = num1 + num2
        print("The Result of",num1,"+",num2,"=", sum)

    def sub(num1, num2): 
        diff = num1 - num2
        print("The Result of",num1,"-",num2,"=", diff)

    def mult(num1, num2):
        product = num1 * num2
        print("The Result of",num1,"*",num2,"=", product)

    def div(num1, num2):
        if num2 == 0:
            print("The Result of",num1,"/",num2,"= You cannot divide by Zero")
        else:
            quotient = num1 / num2
            print("The Result of",num1,"/",num2,"=", quotient)

    #If-else
    if num1 < rangeLower or num1 > rangeHigher or num2 < rangeLower or num2 > rangeHigher:
        print("The input values are outside the input ranges.")
        print("Please check the number and try again.")
        print("Thanks for using our calculator")
    else:
        #Call functions
        add(num1, num2)
        sub(num1, num2)
        mult(num1, num2)
        div(num1, num2)
        print("Thanks for using this calculator!")

    def scalc(p1):
        astring = p1.split(",")
        num1 = float(astring[0])
        num2 = float(astring[1])
        if astring[2] == "+":
            add(num1, num2)
        elif astring[2] == "-":
            sub(num1, num2)
        elif astring[2] == "*":
            mult(num1, num2)
        elif astring[2] == "/":
            div(num1, num2)
        return num1, num2

    p1 = input("Enter two numbers and an operator, each separated by a comma: ")
    scalc(p1)
```

Comment: You're not passing any values to your functions (you should have included at least one in your question!), nor are you capturing the result. `add()` should presumably be `result = add(num1, num2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does it. There were a couple errors. First, in Python you start counting at 0, so you wanted to use  `astring[2]` instead of `astring[3]`. Also you needed a value to be returned:

```
def scalc(p1):
    astring = p1.split(",")
    print(astring)
    num1 = float(astring[0])
    num2 = float(astring[1])
    if astring[2] == "+":
        add(num1,num2)
    elif astring[2] == "-":
       sub(num1,num2)
    elif astring[2] == "*":
        mult(num1,num2)
    elif astring[2] == "/":
        div(num1,num2)
    return value

p1 = input("Enter two numbers and an operator, each separated by a comma: ")
scalc(p1)
```

Example:

```
input: "20,30,+"

Out[2]: 50.0
```

Comment: Oh! Okay I see I had 3 instead of 2.  I fixed that, but now I still need to replace num1 and num2 in the original code with the new values.

Comment: Honestly, I don't even know if we need to keep the original code except for the formula functions.  I could just delete the rest of the code where num1 and num2 are originally given values and use the new function we were given.

Comment: Okay, so you added the formulas for add, substract, divide, multiply... but I already had those formulas in functions built from previous assignments.  We were told to use our existing functions.  So instead of returning the value, I need to return num1 and num2 so that my other functions can use them.  I updated the code in the original post.

Comment: So, right now that I changed my 3 to a 2, the code runs; however, calling one of my formula functions returns the original num1 and num2 from the previous input.

Comment: You're missing arguments in your functions, you should consider adding them so your main function is functional. Because this is homework I shouldn't help your further, but should be enough for you to find the right way

Comment: thank you, that was the problem.  I updated my post with the answer.  You can update your answer and I can select it as the best answer.  Keep what you have in it, just add that I needed the arguments passed to the variables.

Comment: There it is! I'm glad I helped